# What is the most reliable way to redirect a visitor to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I had a pure PHP page whose purpose is to do a lot of stuff (it takes 4-5 seconds for it to load), and then redirect the user to another page.

Recently, I put a little bit of HTML (a loading gif to be precise) just before the beginning of the PHP script so that the visitor knows the page is doing stuff and hopefully doesn't close the page.

The problem is that now I can't use PHP's header function to redirect the visitor since the HTML code sends the headers before PHP can do so.

I need a really, really reliable way to redirect the visitor in my case. I want it to work on any device (desktop, mobile, tablet, etc.) and any browser.  For now, I think that echoing a meta refresh tag is the best way to accomplish this. What do you think?

Comment: How do you determine if they are getting redirected? You possibly could use .htaccess/web.config. That would be before any PHP processing beings.

Comment: Hi Chris, this is exactly what the PHP script does - it decides where to send the visitor.

Comment: nothing is *really reliable* when it comes to users, nothing will stop them leaving the page, so you should just code for that

Comment: The only reliable cross browser method is to output a link with a big 'work complete, click here to proceed to next page'. As already mentiaoned by others you can find many ways to redirect but you cannot exclude failure and must code knowing that.

Comment: *"The problem is that now I can't use PHP's header function to redirect the visitor since the HTML code sends the headers before PHP can do so."* - Why can't you move your HTML below PHP?

Answer (score 2):

The browser may not wait for the request to complete once it reads your meta tag, which might leave your script in an inconsistent state. You could hack this by adding javascript which looks for a marker on the page that is only sent after your script is done, and redirect from js. But what you really want to do is send a short response with just your loading gif and which makes an ajax call to the server for the operation, and do the redirect once you get a successful response. But then, you should've done that on your original page in the first place.

Comment: Hi Miki, I am echoing the meta refresh tag in the very end of the PHP script.

Comment: Then it should work. You could also inject JS, no idea if one is more reliable than the other. Still an odd way to do it, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can redirect user using javascript. Use

```
window.location="";
```

or

```
window.location.href=""
```

---

Comment: is js ever *really reliable* ?

Comment: I thought of that, but is it reliable? Is it supported by all devices and browsers?

Comment: you can check list of supported browsers here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp

Comment: A good majority of devices support Javascript but that doesn't mean the user will have it enabled.

Answer (score 1):

1. Send HTTP header on the server side.

`Location: http://foobar.com`

2. Render meta redirect on the client side.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://foobar.com/">`

3. Render a link on the client side.

`<a href="http://foobar.com">Redirecting to http://foobar.com. or click here</a>`

This way, if the client browser doesn't support standards for automated redirects, then they opportunistically have a link to follow through with.

I wouldn't bother with Javascript, since if they don't conform to above standards, likely this catch will not get anyone additionally.

This is pretty standard practice.